# Selenium webElement property change

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an application with selenium.There are no normal labels like id,tag by which I will be able to find an element. So I was using the xpath[driver.findElement(By.xpath())]. But now i find that some of the xpaths of the WebElement changing dynamically while runtime and so my test cases are failing.Even the relative xpath option is not available for the HTML.I am pasting a part of the html of the AUT. Please let me know how to handle this scenario .

```
<div>
<button class="btn btn-primary ng-hide" ng-click="unlockOrder('/content/boss/en/dashboard');" ng-show="enableUnlockButton" type="button">Unlock Order</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="discardOrder('/content/boss/en/create-order/pre-order-options');" type="button">Discard Order</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveOrder(showSaveButton && ban_search.$valid);" ng-disabled="showSaveButton==false || ban_search.$invalid" type="button" disabled="disabled">Save Order</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rely on the *button text*:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//button[. = "Unlock Order"]'))
```

where `.` refers to button's text.

Comment: I am new to this,so can you please explain your code above?

Comment: @Reema the expression inside the quotes is an xpath expression, the dot refers to button's text. Hope this makes things clearer. If it works for you, don't forget to accept the answer (checkbox on the left). Thanks.

Comment: ,ok i got it, but here there is a problem, the html that i posted is just a part, and fortunately there is button with different text. What about this piece of code?

<li ng-class="{active: active, disabled: disabled}" ng-repeat="orgOption in organizationTypeOptions" ng-click="selectContext(orgOption.key, orgOption.value, orgOption.isDisabled)" disabled="disabled" active="orgOption.isActive" heading="NON-EXISTING Organization" class="ng-isolate-scope">
  <a tab-heading-transclude="" ng-click="select()" class="ng-binding">NON-EXISTING Organization</a>
</li>

Comment: I tried to use driver.findElement(By.xpath(property)

(here property = /heading[. = "NON-EXISTING Organization"], and I am passing the value from a properties file)
I am doing anything wrong here? because this is not working out. :(

Comment: @Reema with the `a` tag you can do it easier: `By.linkText('NON-EXISTING Organization')`.

Comment: I need the elements to be identified by a common means like either xpath or linkText, but according to my framework, best would be to select any one way. For the time being i have planned to work with xpath bcoz i find that as the most stable one .so in this case what should i do?

Comment: @Reema not sure about your reasons not to use `linkText`, but here is how you can use By.xpath: `//a[. = "NON-EXISTING Organization"]`.

Comment: @Reema `property = /heading[. = "NON-EXISTING Organization"]` is incorrect. Heading is an attribute not a tag...you could have rather gone for `//li[@heading='NON-EXISTING Organization']` where li is an element (tag) and heading is an attribute...thanks...